# Inflation-restriction sequence for profinite groups

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, abelian-categories, class-field-theory, derived-functors

I recently learnt about profinite group cohomology to do class field theory and I am looking for **a proof of the profinite version of the inflation-restriction sequence which hopefully just uses the version for usual group cohomology** (in particular $0\to Br(L/K)\to Br(K)\to Br(L)\to 0$ for $L/K$ a Galois and finite field extension) for profinite groups. Is there a proof not using the Hochschild–Serre spectral sequence. I found a proof in Cassel Frohlich p126 which uses the inflation-restriction sequence for usual group cohomology, which seems be to incorrect by Kevin Buzzard [https://www.ma.ic.ac.uk/~buzzard/errata.pdf](https://www.ma.ic.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/errata.pdf).

My idea is that maybe the inflation-restriction sequence for usual group cohomology can be naturally generalizes since the usual group cohomology and profinite group cohomology are both defined using derived functors, one of general modules and the other for discrete modules. In this case, I need a more abstract version of the inflation-restriction sequence, for example for general derived functors, but I didn't find anything about this generalization.

Alternatively, I guess I can also develop the theory of profinite group cohomology from scratch. This takes a lot of work though.

Edit: **is this correct?** to generally prove the inflation-restriction sequence might be hard without spectral sequences, but I guess we don't need it to show the special case applying to Brauer groups.

$$0\to Br(L/K)\to Br(K)\to Br(L)\to 0.$$

The Brauer group can be thought of direct limit of those of the finite subextensions with inflation being the transition maps. By Hilbert 90 and the usual inflation-restriction sequence, this direct limit is just direct sum. Since the maps in the above sequence are induced by component-wise inflation and restriction, the kernels and images in this sequence are direct sum of those in the inflation-restriction sequence for finite subextensions. Then the exactness naturally generalizes to the above seqeunce.

Comment: If memory serves me right, it depends on what hypotheses you want. Profinite group cohomology is a colimit of finite group cohomology, i.e. $H^n(G,A)=\colim H^n(G/N,A^N)$, where $N$ runs through the open normal subgroups. If the hypotheses for the usual inflation-restriction sequence are satisfied *level-wise* for this colimit, you obtain the profinite inflation-restriction sequence as colimit of the level-wise inflation-restriction sequences in the finite case.

Comment: The assumptions holding level-wise is a stronger assumption than them holding only in the colimit. I don't know a way of obtaining the stronger inflation-restriction sequence without using more general theory, e.g. spectral sequences. The weaker version suffices for all the applications to Brauer groups, though (the relevant hypotheses are satisfied level-wise as Hilbert 90 holds level-wise).

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you! Could you explain what you mean by levelwise?

Comment: Fix a closed normal subgroup $K\trianglelefteq G$. For each open normal subgroup $N\trianglelefteq G$, there is an inflation-restriction sequence $0\rightarrow H^ n(G/KN,A^{KN})\rightarrow H^n(G/N,A^N)\rightarrow H^n(KN/N,A^N)$. This sequence is natural in $N$ and taking the colimit yields the inflation-restriction sequence $0\rightarrow H^n(G/K,A^K)\rightarrow H^n(G,A)\rightarrow H^n(K,A)$. If $H^i(KN/N,A^N)=0$ for all $N$ and $0<i<n$, these sequences are all exact by the group cohomology case, so the profinite sequence in the colimit is exact too. That's what I mean by level-wise.

Comment: @Thorgott I see what you mean by level-wise, but does Hilbert 90 apply to $H^i(KN/N,A^N)$? The Galois group of $A^N$ should be $G/N$ but not $KN/N$.

Comment: If $G=Gal(F)$ for some field $F$, then $K=Gal(E)$ for some Galois extension $E/F$ and $N=Gal(E^{\prime})$ for some finite Galois extension $E^{\prime}/F$. Then, $KN=Gal(E\cap E^{\prime})$, so $KN/N=Gal(E^{\prime}/E\cap E^{\prime})$. Now, $A=F^{sep,\times}$, hence $A^N=(E^{\prime})^{\times}$ and $KN/N$ acts on $A^N$ via the Galois action. Thus, $H^1(KN/N,A^N)=H^1(E^{\prime}/E\cap E^{\prime},(E^{\prime})^{\times})=0$ by Hilbert 90.

Comment: @Thorgott I see. That's indeed a good way to show the special case without spectral sequence. Thank you!